# VSCode Intellisense with Python C extension module (petsc4py)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, python-c-api, petsc

I'm currently using a python module called petsc4py (https://pypi.org/project/petsc4py/). My main issue is that none of the typical intellisense features seems to work with this module.

I'm guessing it might have something to do with it being a C extension module, but I am not sure exactly why this happens. I initially thought that intellisense was unable to look inside ".so" files, but it seems that numpy is able to do this with the `array` object, which in my case is inside a file called `multiarray.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu` (check example below).

Does anyone know why I see this behaviour in the petsc4py module. Is there anything that I (or the developers of petsc4py) can do to get intellisense to work?

### Example:

```
import sys
import petsc4py
petsc4py.init(sys.argv)
from petsc4py import PETSc

x_p = PETSc.Vec().create()
x_p.setSizes(10)
x_p.setFromOptions()

u_p = x_p.duplicate()


import numpy as np

x_n = np.array([1,2,3])
u_n = x_n.copy()
```

In this example, when trying to work with a `Vec` object from petsc4py, doing `u_p.duplicate()` cannot find the function and the suggestion is simply a repetition of the function immediately before. However, using an `array` from numpy, doing `u_n.copy()` works perfectly.

[image: example with petsc4py]
[image: example with numpy]

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: still having the problem. I'm working with https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling in-place then you're bumping up against https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/197.